# Check and warn about Google Mail Storage Usage automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I need to automatically check and warn (send mail) if my gmail size increases about a particular limit (say > 25 GB) so that I could cleanup my inbox before it reaches the full capacity of 30 GB.

I thought of using Google App Scripts for this. But I could get only the size of the Google drive using 'DriveApp.getStorageUsed()'. But I couldnt find a similar method for GmailApp.

Is there any other way I could use Google App scripts to monitor the size of my Inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Gmail:
You can use advanced services and https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-accounts and reporting https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports

**total_quota_in_mb integer Total storage (in MB) for the user.**

**used_quota_in_mb  integer Total storage (in MB) used by the user.**

For Drive:
You can use the funcions listed below: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getStorageUsed()

**getStorageLimit()**

Gets the number of bytes the user is allowed to store in Drive.

**Return**

Integer — the number of bytes the user is allowed to store in Drive

**getStorageUsed()**

Gets the number of bytes the user is currently storing in Drive.

**Return**

Integer — the number of bytes the user is currently storing in Drive